# Program saying file already in use but i closed it C#

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = @"comics.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                var myComicsFile = File.Create(path);
                myComicsFile.Close();
                FileStream file = new FileStream("comics.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                TextWriter write = new StreamWriter(path);
            }
            else if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                FileStream file = new FileStream("comics.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                TextWriter write = new StreamWriter(path);
            }
        }
```

I keep getting the error System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process'
I thought I had fixed it by closing the file after i created it the opening it but i get the error still.  Not sure what the correct solution is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: oh no you didnt

Comment: `using (var fs = new FileStream(...){...}`

Comment: Why are you opening a FileStream to "comics.txt", and then a TextWriter to "path" which contains "comics.txt"? In short: Why are you opening the same file twice? Also, you're never closing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, there is no need to create a file empty and open it, instead use the appropriate `FileMode` Instead

[FileMode.OpenOrCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> **OpenOrCreate**
>
> Specifies that the operating system should open a file if it exists;
>   otherwise, a new file should be created. If the file is opened with
>   FileAccess.Read, Read permission is required. If the file access is
>   FileAccess.Write, Write permission is required. If the file is opened
>   with FileAccess.ReadWrite, both Read and Write permissions are
>   required.

When you use a BCL method always check the documentation for clues about how to use it, in-particular look for if something supports `IDisposable` if it does ALWAYS use a `using` statement when you can

[using Statement (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of
>   IDisposable objects.

in short you could have just done this

```
 using (var file = new FileStream("comics.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    using(var TextWriter write = new StreamWriter(file))
    {
       // stuff here
    }
```

Basically, when `using` a using statement with a stream derivative, it closes and disposes any unmanaged resources like file handles. in your case, you have left the File Handle dangling and hence your problem

Answer (score 1):

Use the “using” statement to ensure file is closed.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Answer (score 0):

You can nest `using` to take away a lot of the potential problems (like you have experienced already) by automatically calling `dispose`. For example

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\file.txt", FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
            {
                string output = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```